# Injecting Angular2 Components as a class or attribute rather than a tag

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components

In Angular1 you could directly insert the HTML into the index.html or index.php like this:

```
<div ng-controller="pricingController">
  {{price}} - Total Cost
</div>
```

In Angular2 you have to use a component which forces you to use a TemplateURL in the component.

I want to do something more similar to Angular 1's format.

Something like this directly in the HTML:

```
<div ngComponent="pricing-component">
  {{price}} - Total Price
</div>
```

Rather than this:

```
<pricing-component></pricing-component>
```

Comment: What is the benefit that you get?

Comment: Are you looking for directive?

Comment: The benefit is it bypasses a lot of the templateURL caching problems that I have with Angular

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use an attribute you can use the attribute selector, and a directive. A directive is a component without a template. Or better said, a component is a directive with a template:

```
<div pricing>
  {{price}} - Total Price
</div>
```

And your `Pricing` will have this selector in the directive annotation:

```
@Directive({
  selector : '[pricing]'
})
export class PricingDirective {}
```

Comment: Oh ok I see, so you can do all the same stuff with a directive that you can do with a component, do you need to import anything in?  Like `import { Directive } from '@angular/core`

Comment: Yep and yep ;) except you can't use `@ViewChild` and stuff like that, but that makes sense, because it's not a view